# React navigation not going to other screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to navigate to other screen using TouchableHighlight / button but it does not navigate to the other screen .
there are no error's .
Nothing happens when i press the TouchableHighlight/button its in the same screen .

```
trackButton() {
    const navigation = this.props.navigation;


    return (
        <View style={styles.footer}>
            {/* <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='transparent' onPress={() => this.gotoTrackingScreen()}> */}
            <TouchableHighlight underlayColor='transparent' onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('faq')}>
           
           
                <Text style={this.trackingButtonStyleOS()}>
                    START TRACKING
                </Text>
            </TouchableHighlight>  
            {/* <Button
      onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Tracking')}
      title="Chat with Lucy"
    /> */}
               
        </View>
    );
}
```

we are currently using react navigation:1.0.1 beta

StackNavigator is implemented in index.android.js

```
const BeaconApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: App,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  },
  Tracking: {
    screen: TrackingScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null
    }
  }})
```

Comment: Please update your question with your navigator implementation so that others can better understand your problem and help.

Comment: @Davis: You may want to have a try on v3 instead of still using v1 beta

Answer (score 0):

I think that the naming of your component didn't come with the standards.
I saw that you try to make trackButton component which later will be implemented by TrackingScreen.
React will determined function as a component if it written in **UpperCamelCase**, not **lowerCamelCase**. Props will not be received in your component because it will be assumed as regular function and regular function don't have props passing feature.

Because of that, your trackButton component didn't receive the props.navigation and nothing happen when you click the button